# Add controller as a child controller opened from a child view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm developing an iOS 5.0+ app with latest SDK.

I have a view controller with its view (**VC1**). Inside this view I have a custom child `UIView` (**view2**).

From this child view I'm going to open another view controller (**VC2**) and I want to do it adding **VC2** as a child controller for **VC1** but I don't know how to do it.

Now, on **view2** I have this method:

```
- (void) handleLongClick:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    SettingsDialogViewController* dialog = [[SettingsDialogViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GaugeSettingsDialogViewController" bundle:nil];

    dialog.view.frame = self.superview.superview.bounds;
    [self.superview.superview addSubview:dialog.view];
}
```

But If I do this, `dialog` will be released and I don't want to add an instance variable because it will be at memory all the time.

**How can I add VC2 as a child controller for VC1?**

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to create an instance variable/property of the parent `UIViewController.`  Can you clarify?  `UIPopoverController` does something similar, storing the child view controller in a retained property.

Comment: Because it will be on memory all the time, wasting memory.

Answer (score 0):

> But If I do this, dialog will be released and I don't want to add an instance variable because it will be at memory every time.

Even if you do not, it will be in memory with a one less retain count. But you do not need to have it as a member variable only to show.

There are many ways to make transition from a view to another view. I see you have view controllers both of your views. So I will show you the easiest(common) ways.

- Push to the navigationstack

If your view has a navigation controller then you can push the second controller to the navigation stack. While showing VC1

```
UINavigationController *navigationller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:VC1];
// show VC1
```

Then show VC2 like this

```
- (void) handleLongClick:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
SettingsDialogViewController* dialog = [[SettingsDialogViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GaugeSettingsDialogViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:dialog animated:YES];
}
```

You get automatically a back button on navigation bar.

- Show as modal

For that you do not need to have navigation controller.

```
- (void) handleLongClick:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
SettingsDialogViewController* dialog = [[SettingsDialogViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GaugeSettingsDialogViewController" bundle:nil];

[self presentViewController:dialog animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Of course you need to add an action to close it again, if you want. On navigation controller you get automatically a back button on navigation bar. Please try both and decide what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't do `[self presentViewController:dialog animated:YES completion:nil];` because `- (void) handleLongClick:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer` is on an `UIView`.

Comment: Then your view has to tell his view controller that he recognized the action (eg. using delegate). The view controller should be responsible for changing views and not the views. A view should not do that, it is against MVC pattern.